# How do I (programmatically) ensure that a dll contains definitions for all exported functions?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this lib

```
//// testlib.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

void __declspec(dllexport) test();
int __declspec(dllexport) a();
```

If I omit the definition for `a()` and `test()` from my testlib.cpp, the library still compiles, because the **interface** [1] is still valid. (If I use them from a client app then they won't link, obviously)

Is there a way I can ensure that when the obj is created (which I gather is the compiler's job) it actually looks for the definitions of the functions that I explicitly exported, and fails if doesn't ?

This is not related to any real world issue. Just curious.

---

[1] [MSVC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=vs-2019#remarks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Partially because a `dllexport` declaration might legally not even be implemented in the same DLL, let alone library, but be a mere forward declaration for something provided by yet another DLL.

Especially it's impossible to decide on the object level. It's just another forward declaration like any other.

You can dump the exported symbols once the DLL has been linked, but there is no common tool for checking completeness.

Ultimately, you can't do without a client test application which attempts to load all exported interfaces. You can't check that on compile time yet. Even just successfully *linking* the test application isn't enough, you have to actually run it.

It gets even worse if there are delay-loaded DLLs (and yes, there usually are), because now you can't even check for completeness unless you actually call at least one symbol from each involved DLL.

Tools like Dependency Walker etc. exist for this very reason.

Comment: Accepted because I feel this is the most useful and complete enough answer.

Answer (score 2):

You asked

"Is there a way I can ensure that when the obj is created (which I gather is the compiler's job) it actually looks for the definitions of the functions that I explicitly exported, and fails if doesn't ?"

When you load a DLL then the actual function binding is happenning at runtime(late binding of functions) so it is not possible for the compiler to know if the function definition are available in the DLL or not. Hope this answer to your query.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I (programmatically) ensure that a dll contains definitions for all exported functions?

### In general, in standard C++11 (read the document [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)), you cannot

Because C++11 does not know about DLL or [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker). It might sometimes make sense to dynamically load code which does not define a function which you pragmatically know will never be called (e.g. an incomplete DLL for drawing shapes, but you happen to know that circles would *never* be drawn in your particular usage, so the loaded DLL might not define any `class Circle` related code. In standard C++11, every called function *should be defined* somewhere (in some *other* [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))).

Look also into [Qt](https://qt.io/) vision of [plugins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html).

Read Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) book. Notice that on Linux, plugins loaded with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) have a different semantics than Windows DLLs. **The evil is in the details**

---

In practice, you might consider using some *recent* variant of the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and develop your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to check that. This could require several weeks of work.

Alternatively, adapt the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) for your needs. Again, budget several weeks of work.

See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report and think about C++ cross compilers (e.g. compiling on Windows a plugin for a [RaspBerry Pi](https://raspberrypi.org/))

Consider also runtime code generation frameworks like [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). You might think of generating at runtime the missing stubs or functions (and fill appropriately function pointers with them, or even [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)). C++ exceptions could also be an additional issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your DLL contains calls to the functions, the linker will fail if a definition isn't provided for those functions.  It doesn't matter if the calls are never executed, only that they exist.

```
//// testlib.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#ifndef DLLEXPORT
#define DLLEXPORT(TYPE) TYPE __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

DLLEXPORT(void) test();
DLLEXPORT(int) a();


//// testlib_verify.c
#define DLLEXPORT(TYPE)

void DummyFunc()
{
#include testlib.h
}
```

This macro-based solution only works for functions with no parameters, but it should be easy to extend.